# UV Editor Not Displaying Selected Faces

Tags: uv, 3d-view, transforms, uv-image-editor

While in Edit Mode, selecting the geometry in the 3D viewport doesn't cause the same selected geometry to show up in the UV Editor window.

It's only when I begin modifying the selected UVs that the UV Editor updates. At this point I can cancel the transform and the newly selected faces remain.

This problem is happening to only one object in the scene. The object was working fine previously, so I must have enabled/disabled something unintentionally.

I've checked that 'View > Update Automatically' is enabled. Given that it's happening to only this object however, I don't think the problem is with a UV Editor setting. But I don't know what object-specific setting would cause this behaviour.

[image: Doing/Cancelling a transformation keeps the selected UVs on display]
*Doing/Cancelling a transformation keeps the selected UVs on display*
[image: Selecting UVs doesn't affect any change]
*Selecting UVs doesn't affect any change*
[image: Starting to scale those UVs then causes them to appear]
*Starting to scale those UVs then causes them to appear*

Any help would be welcome, cheers.

Comment: You should upload a .blend file, so we can test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my objects.  I believe the issue came up after I joined several meshes each with a mirror modifier.  I removed the modifier and reapplied and it appears that the issue has resolved itself.